# "After the tea <got colder> <cooled down>, we begin drinking it."

Tags: difference

my own example:
Water boils in the kettle.
We take a tea bag, put it into a cup, then pour the water into the cup.
The water in our cup is about 100 degrees Celsius.
We wait a little bit.
The temperature goes down to 70-80 degrees Celsius.
We begin drinking the tea.

That is:
**(1)** *After the tea **got cold**, we begin drinking it*. — I think it's incorrect since the tea is not cold. It's still hot, but not very hot.
Probably the right way to say it would be:
**(2)** *After the tea **got colder**, we begin drinking it*. — is it correct?
**(3)** *After the tea **cooled down**, we begin drinking it*. — is it correct?

If (2) and (3) are both correct, then what is the difference between them?

Comment: This might be specific to US English, or even my specific region, but I find "the tea cooled **off**" more natural than "the tea cooled **down**".

Answer (score 2):

Both 2 and 3 need a bit of correction first. They should be:

2. "*After the tea got colder, we **began** drinking it.*"
3. "*After the tea cooled down, we **began** drinking it.*"

"began" should be used assuming it is also a description of a past action, following the action of getting cold or cooling down, which was already described as occuring in the past.

That being said, I think "cooled down" is more natural for hot beverages (drinks). I've heard "cooled down" used much more frequently than "got colder". In fact, I'm not sure if I've *ever* heard anyone say "got colder" to mean what you described.

"got colder" could possibly also cause misunderstanding to some readers, since "got cold" is a very common way of saying that a hot beverage got cold *past the point* of what is normally considered a good temperature for enjoying it as intended.

Comment: Yes, *"got cold"* usually means reached room temperature when applied to food and drink.